# Video match anlysis

Tags: video, video-processing

I am looking forward to find an algorithm to detect a pattern in a given video file. Actually I am going to index moments in a tennis match video at which service (first kick after a goal) is shot.

PS1: sorry for broken English.
PS2: I DO NOT know anything about tennis except that you need a ball to play!!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [opencv](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/)
For a tennis ball in a video stream I would look at simply matching a patch of white pixels, then combine this with movement prediction (the ball has to be close to and on a continual path from the last frame)

Answer (score 0):

Tennis? Goal? You mean serve? Google for OpenCV. Have you got any experience in the field of pattern recognition or image processing? I suggest you look into them.

Generally in most sport involving a ball you are looking to track it in some way. You can use edge detection algorithms after applying a few filters to accomplish this.

I would highly recommend learning OPENCV by O'reilly publishers. Very good book that also explains image processing concepts.

Your project is ambitious! Which is good. Learn up your concepts first then all this will seem very easy! Good Luck!